# Copy values from Fridays to the following Saturday in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 8760 hours worth of data and have added a datetime index against it. What I want to do is replace all the values that are on Saturdays with the values from the previous Friday.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(hourly_data, names=['values'])
df.index = pd.date_range('2015-01-01','2016-01-01', freq='H')[:8760]
df['weekday'] = df.index.weekday
```

So the df format is as follows:

```
                     value  weekday
2015-01-03 00:00:00     21        5
2015-01-03 01:00:00     21        5
2015-01-03 02:00:00     21        5
...
2015-01-03 00:00:00     12        6
2015-01-03 01:00:00     12        6
2015-01-03 02:00:00     12        6
```

And what I want to get out is:

```
                     value  weekday
2015-01-03 00:00:00     21        5
2015-01-03 01:00:00     21        5
2015-01-03 02:00:00     21        5
...
2015-01-03 00:00:00     21        6
2015-01-03 01:00:00     21        6
2015-01-03 02:00:00     21        6
```

But I've got no idea how to get there. Something to do with `offset` perhaps?

Comment: IIUC I think you can do `df.loc[df['weekday'].dt.weekday==5] = df.shift(-1)` I think

Comment: That's not working for me. I've added an example of the dataframe showing the columns

Comment: Got it. I can do `df.loc[df.index.weekday==5] = df.shift(-24)`, and I don't even need the `weekday` helper column anymore.

Comment: Yes if you have regular intervals then you just need to `shift` by the interval amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) and a mask to select the rows you wish to modify and assign the values [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas.DataFrame.shift)ed by your regular interval:

```
df.loc[df.index.weekday==5] = df.shift(-24)
```